# Prove $\liminf_{n\to \infty } \|u_n\|_{L^2}\geq \|u\|_{L^2}$ if $u_n\to u$ weakly.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Prove $$\liminf_{n\to \infty } \|u_n\|_{L^2}\geq \|u\|_{L^2}$$ if $u_n\to u$ weakly in $L^2$.

**Attempts**

Since $u_n\to u$ weakly in $L^2$ in particularly, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int (u_n-u)u=0.$$
I tried to play with this and use the fact that $$0=\int u_n^2=\int u_n(u_n-u)+\int u_nu,$$
but it's not conclusif.

I also tried :

$$\int(u_n^2-u^2)=\int(u_n-u)u_n+\int u(u_n-u)$$
but I can't prove that the limit is positive.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
\|u_{n}\|_{L^{2}}&=\sup\left\{\left|\int u_{n}v\right|: v\in L^{2},~\|v\|_{L^{2}}\leq 1\right\}\\
&\geq\left|\int u_{n}v\right|
\end{align*}
for all such $v$, then taking $\liminf$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n}\|u_{n}\|_{L^{2}}\geq\left|\lim_{n}\int u_{n}v\right|=\left|\int uv\right|,
\end{align*}
once again the formula
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{L^{2}}=\sup\left\{\left|\int uv\right|: v\in L^{2},~\|v\|_{L^{2}}\leq 1\right\},
\end{align*}
the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|u_n\|^2_{L^2}=\int u_n^2=\int(u_n-u+u)^2=\int(u_n-u)^2+2\int u(u_n-u)+\int u^2$$
$$\geq 2\int (u_n-u)u+\int u^2$$
By taking the $\liminf$, the claim follow.